# Supremum and infimum of an inequality

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I feel like this is elementary but I can't seem to determine the supremum/infimum (if they exist) of the following example:

Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 > 2x + 8\}$

I rewrote it as $$x^2 -2x - 8 > 0$$
$$(x-4)(x+2) > 0 $$

So it is clear that there is no supremum.

But how do I determine the infimum?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$S = (-\infty,-2)\cup (4,\infty)$, thus $\inf(S) = -\infty$, and $\sup(S) = \infty$.